# JtextArea cursor position after keypress of ENTER

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keylistener, key-bindings

Guys weird problem im facing
Basically i have 2 textAreas... (diplaybox and textbox)

while typing in textbox, the moment "Enter" is pressed i want all the text entered in textbox to go to displaybox... and textbox should be empty... 
it all works fine, except...

after the text is transfered the cursor position of the textbox isnt on the topmost left side... it is somehow blinking on one line below that!(possibly because "ENTER" still got excecuted)... please see code
any ideas?

thanks in advance... just need the cursor to go back to the topmost left like how it is when we start typing ... without having to use KeyReleased event... something isnt feeling right... im sure this isnt he way it is actually done.. what say?

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)// | (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B))
    { //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

    displaybox.append(textbox.getText() + "\n");

    //textbox.setCaretPosition(0);
    //textbox.setText("");
    System.out.println(textbox.getCaretPosition());
    }
}

 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{}

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {textbox.setCaretPosition(0);
        textbox.setText("");
        System.out.println(textbox.getCaretPosition());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All Swing components work by using `Key Bindings`. The default binding for the `Enter` key is to add a newline string to the text area. If you want to change the functionality of the `Enter` key then change the default Action. Don't attempt to use a KeyListener.

Check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a program to list all the default bindings as well as a link to the Swinng tutorial on `How to Use Key Bindings`. If you run the program you will find that the `Enter` key invokes an `Action` identified by the *"insert-break"* tag in the `ActionMap`. So to replace the `Action` you can do something like:

```
Action enter = new AbstractAction()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        displayBox.append( textBox.getText() + "\n" );
        textBox.setText("");
    }
};

textBox.getActionMap().put("insert-break", enter);
```

The problem with using the KeyListener is that the default Action is still invoked AFTER you process the KeyEvent.

Comment: Nice! kinda lill high for my level... but seems brilliant
going to spend time and understand Key Bindings... thanx